# a special solution to the java Permutation (recursion)?

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

According to the textbook, the writer asked me to use a special method to realize the permutation in java. 
To put it more precisely, two functions exist:

`public void static displayPermutation(String s)`  ----which is simply invoke the next function  `displayPermutation("", String s);`
from the perspective of the author, we should move one character from the "s" which is after the comma, to the String which is in the first one step by step using recursion.

However I find my codes don't work despite I make every efforts to realize that.
Here is my code:

```
public static void displayPermuation(String s){
    displayPermuation("", s);
}
public static void displayPermuation(String s1, String s2){
    if(s2.length() == 0){
        System.out.println(s1);
        return;
    }else{
        for(int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++){
            s1 = String.format(s1 + "%s", s2.charAt(i));
            s2 = String.format("%s%s", s2.substring(0, i), s2.substring(i + 1, s2.length()));
            displayPermuation(s1, s2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"? what do you expect to happen and what is the actual result?

Comment: After the first iteration of your for loop, the strings `s1` and `s2` are no longer what you assume they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below the solution for this problem. The function displayPermuation with two params will be written as the following.
The reason this doesn't work is that you are changing s1 & s2 in your for loop so it effects the for loop iterator.

Suppose

s2 = 'abc'

So for loop runs 3 times

then we make s2 = bc.

so the length becomes 2

If you just don't change the value of s2 in your for loop it will work fine as in the below code.

```
public static void displayPermuation(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s2.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println(s1);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
        displayPermuation(s1+s2.charAt(i), s2.substring(0,i)+s2.substring(i+1, s2.length()));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.